# how can i limit the value of a node value?

Tags: node-editor, drivers, vector

I want the value of this node's y-location between somewhere around these 2 values (preferably using drivers)

[image]
[image]

what's the best way to do this? I plan on giving this to 3 other nodes as well

Comment: At the moment those are just typed in values - which can be easily limited by not typing something out of range ;)  The question is, in which way will these values change, where do they get changes from? Depending on the source of the variaton the solutions might differ.

Comment: first, i  recommend not asking "what is the best way..." because you have a high risk that your question will be closed. Better ask, "what are ways to..."

Comment: @Chris didn't know that. will definitely keep that in mind

Comment: i had to learn this the hard way too....my questions were closed in minutes ... ;)

Answer (score 1):

you can clamp two values by this:

[image]

This is just an example.

The expression is

```
min(max(yourMinValue, valueToEvaluate), yourMaxValue)
```

or

```
clamp(valueToEvaluate,min,max)
```

result of my example:

[image]